# implementing a spellcheck algorithm

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Compare two text files - spellchecking program in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8512261/compare-two-text-files-spellchecking-program-in-c)

I'm writing a spellcheck program that will compare a user's text file with a dictionary to see if the words they entered are in the dictionary.

The dictionary loops through once and then it gets stuck on the final word. How can I loop through the dictionary again?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main (void) 
{ 
    FILE * fp1, *fp2;               /* file handle  */ 
    char userword[100]; 
    char dictword[100];
    char fname[40];
    int i, j, ca, cb; 

    //  printf("Enter filename to compare to dictionary:");
    //  fgets(fname,40,stdin);
    //  fp1 = fopen(fname,"r");
    fp1 = fopen("userdoc.txt", "r"); /* open file for reading, use for
                                      * time being until name input resolved*/  
    fp2 =fopen("dictionary.txt", "r");

    if (fp1 == NULL) 
    { 
            printf("Could not open file for output.\n"); 
            return 0; 
    } 
    if (fp2 == NULL)
    {
        printf("Cannot open %s for reading \n", fname);
        exit(1);        // terminate program
    }

    for (i=0; userword[i]; i++)  
    {               
        fscanf(fp1, "%s", &userword); 
        printf("The word being checked is %s\n", userword); 

        j=getc(fp2);
        while (dictword[j] != EOF)
        {
            fscanf(fp2, "%s", &dictword); 
            /*printf("The first entry in the dictionary is %s\n", dictword); //check if   dictionary is looping*/

            if(strcmp(dictword, userword) == 0)
                {
                printf("you spelt \"%s\" correctly \n", dictword);
                break; 
            }
            else    
            {   
                /*printf("sorry \" %s \" is not in the dictionary\n", userword);*/
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(fp1);
    fclose(fp2); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: why is `dictword` so big? you always read at its beginning? And did you compile with all warnings enabled? Did you compile for debugging? Did you use your debugger to run your program step by step? You could test it with a small dictionnary file  (of a few words)

Comment: you may have to refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8576785/how-do-i-reset-a-while-loop) .. It may not solve your problem but will give you good hints!

Comment: It compares the first few words in the userdoc as required. if I print the word the dictionary is reading it shows it gets stuck on the last entry and endlessly prints it on screen. There are no warnings when I compile the code.

Comment: Is this homework? Looks very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8512261/compare-two-text-files-spellchecking-program-in-c

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to copy somebody elses work  I just don't get where I'm going wrong

Comment: Hm, I would expect the output "you spelled "spelt" correctly", but instead, I got "sorry "spelt" is not in the dictionary"...

Comment: Not related, but you got a bug here `printf("Cannot open %s for reading \n", fp2);`. fp2 is not a `char *`.

Comment: What I get is - The word being checked is rubbish you spelt "rubbish" correctly

Answer (score 0):

The direct reason why this is failing to do anything is the following line:

```
for (i=0; userword[i]; i++)
```

The loop conditional here is a value, namely the `char` value at index `i`. Notice that, as it stands, your program never initializes the values in this array (hence Basile Starynkevitch suggesting you compile with warnings, e.g. -Wall -Wextra).

If you're getting any output at all, it's just a fluke. The values in your userword[] array might be filled with non-zero values, but they might also be zero in many situations. An interesting thing to consider is that some debugging environments (such as gdb or MSVC) will purposely fill uninitialized memory areas with special values so that you more easily see when this sort of thing happens. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65724/uninitialized-memory-blocks-in-vc) for example.

Sangeeth Saravanaraj is trying to point you in the right direction. In the answer there, notice that the outer loop looks like this:

```
while(fscanf(fp2,"%s", wordcheck)!=EOF)//Reads word from text file into array//
```

This loop does two things in one - it copies a line from `fp2` into `wordcheck`, and *also* checks to see if this operation returned `EOF` - basically an indication that we're at the end of the file. When we're at the end, it breaks from the while loop.

Simply correcting your `for` loop doesn't completely fix your program, though. Think for a second about how you're looping through each word in the dictionary. Your code will only work on a single 'userdoc' word, because after a single pass through your dictionary, you'll be at the end of that file. You'll have to reset the so-called file pointer to the beginning of your dictionary file if you want this method to work:

```
while(fscanf(fp1,"%s", &userword)!=EOF){               

    printf("The word being checked is %s\n", userword); 
    fseek(fp2,0,0);
    while (fscanf(fp2, "%s", &dictword) != EOF)
    { ... }
```

Comment: That's what the upvote button is for! ;)

Answer (score 0):

First off, I would also recommend stepping through your code step-by-step using a tool like [ddd](http://www.gnu.org/s/ddd/) (resp. GNU Debugger). In my opinion, this is one of the best ways to find errors since you can watch the alteration of all variables during execution.

The next problem I see is, that you are using `dictword` uninitialized. What is the content of dictword[j] before stepping into the while-loop the first time?

`fseek(char *stream, long offset, int whence)` is used to set the file position indicator for a stream. There is also a function called `rewind(char *stream)` to reset the position indicator back to the beginning of the file (both included in [stdio.h](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/stdio.h.html)).

For further information, try reading the according [man pages](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/fseek.3.html).

Basically you could just use `rewind(fp1);` at the end of the last loop-cycle (don't forget to reset your loop variable appropriately).

Hope I got your question right ;).